# Let user type only three different characters in an input text field

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to let the user type only three characters? For example, I want to only allow `3`, `6` or `9` in an input text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/UZJn2/

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" class="only369" />



$('.only369').keyup(function(e) {
    if(this.value != '3' && this.value != '6' && this.value != '9') {
        this.value = '';   
    }
});
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster you have '9' two times in the demo, replace one with '6'.

Answer (score 2):

A pure JS solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/eg8Dn/

source:

```
<input id="number" type="number" min="3" max="9" step="3" value="3">

<script>
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keyup',function(ev){
    this.value=!!~['3','6','9'].indexOf(this.value) ? this.value : '';
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help you...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(e)
{
    return (e.charCode == 51 || e.charCode == 54 || e.charCode == 57)
}
</script>
<form>
<input name="name" type="text" onkeypress="return validate(event);" />
</form>
```

If you want to limit the number of occurences, just set the maxlength property of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
"0123456789".replace(/[^369]/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Listen for the `onchange` event on the input element and when the value is different from those three numbers and greater than tree, `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^369]/g, '')"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin. It is **FANTASTIC** :  [**Alphanumeric**](http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/)

**Answer of your question is as simple as this**

```
$('.numericInput').numeric({ichars:'0124578'});
```

### From authors side:

> Did you ever have the need to prevent
>   users from entering certain characters
>   into your form?
>
> Looking at the plugins available at
>   jQuery, I found a great plugin made by
>   Sam Collet called Numeric.
>
> But it was too limited, what if I'm
>   asking the user to create a username?
>   Or what if I need to enter a number
>   with decimals or an IP Address? There
>   is another great plugin called Masked
>   Input by Josh Bush, which can also
>   control user input by defining a mask.
>   The problem however with that was the
>   length of text to be inserted must be
>   defined as well. Again, what if I
>   needed to control input of a username?
>   I can't tell how many characters the
>   user will be using, and I can't force
>   him to use just 8 characters ,so I
>   created AlphaNumeric.
>
> jQuery AlphaNumeric is a javascript
>   control plugin that allows you to
>   limit what characters a user can enter
>   on textboxes or textareas. Have fun.

Comment: This is cool, but what would OP plug with this plugin? OP did not mention jQuery.