# How to allow only a number (digits and decimal point) to be typed in an input?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the way to allow only a valid number typed into a textbox?

For example, user can type in "1.25", but cannot type in "1.a" or "1..".  When user try to type in the next character which will make it an invalid number, they cannot type it in.

Comment: You could use ng-change to call a function that checks the input.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could try this directive to stop any invalid characters from being entered into an input field. (**Update**: this relies on the directive having explicit knowledge of the model, which is not ideal for reusability, see below for a re-usable example)

```
app.directive('isNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope) {    
            scope.$watch('wks.number', function(newValue,oldValue) {
                var arr = String(newValue).split("");
                if (arr.length === 0) return;
                if (arr.length === 1 && (arr[0] == '-' || arr[0] === '.' )) return;
                if (arr.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;
                if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                    scope.wks.number = oldValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It also accounts for these scenarios:

1. Going from a non-empty valid string to an empty string
2. Negative values
3. Negative decimal values

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/) here so you can see how it works.

**UPDATE**

Following Adam Thomas' feedback regarding not including model references directly inside a directive (which I also believe is the best approach) I have updated my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/2/) to provide a method which does not rely on this.

The directive makes use of **bi-directional binding** of local scope to parent scope. The changes made to variables inside the directive will be reflected in the parent scope, and vice versa.

HTML:

```
<form ng-app="myapp" name="myform" novalidate> 
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <number-only-input input-value="wks.number" input-name="wks.name"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.wks =  {number: 1, name: 'testing'};
});
app.directive('numberOnlyInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<input name="{{inputName}}" ng-model="inputValue" />',
        scope: {
            inputValue: '=',
            inputName: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$watch('inputValue', function(newValue,oldValue) {
                var arr = String(newValue).split("");
                if (arr.length === 0) return;
                if (arr.length === 1 && (arr[0] == '-' || arr[0] === '.' )) return;
                if (arr.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;
                if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                    scope.inputValue = oldValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: The jsFiddle appears to be pointing to a different example. You'll need to check for a "-" at the start of the value so that it'll accept a negative number: (value === "-")

Comment: It will validate a negative number too.

Comment: Yes it will validate a negative number, but "-" doesn't make a valid negative number. The main part of the question was to stop users from entering invalid numbers (ie, if I type the key 'A' then it won't even enter it in the input box). Your solution sets more of a validity flag, it doesn't block the input of invalid characters.

Comment: I have now reinstated the answer and updated the jsFiddle following your feedback Mike P. Thanks!

Comment: You've updated your answer! This is the best solution as it doesn't have a "flash" of whatever once was invalid (and then quickly removed) as [most of these solutions do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131100/let-user-type-only-three-different-characters-in-an-input-text-field).

Comment: @user1669811 - I have [created a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19063323/630092) that doesn't require the directive to make a hard reference to the model in the parent scope. I also put in a check for the user typing Space characters (keycode 32). You might find it interesting. If nothing else it's worth looking at to learn how to send messages with data between scopes.

Comment: Should not be referencing the model in directives like this, it breaks reusability. Take a look at [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/angularjs-how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in/19063323#19063323).

Comment: @AdamThomas I have updated my answer following your feedback. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks @GordyD : I updated your code to make an input-price who allow two decimals maximum and transform , to . | jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/233/

Comment: The solution gives error when input dot and then comma.
This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/34ojnnfk/1/
is an alternative as it uses attribute decimal-number to indicate that only numbers are accepted. It works on angular 1.2.1 and up.

Comment: should be add another check if(inputValue==undefined) return;

Comment: @GabrielDelépine, Can I have min and max val restriction for your example

Comment: @Gireesh : For min and max, I recommend you to add a required:true to the directive and use ng-min and ng-max attributes to the input-price tag directly. Then you can make a traditional form validation.
Be careful, the jsfiddle is based on angularJS 1.1 witch is clearly out of date.

Comment: The code has a problem when number is undefined so it force you to put always a value.

Comment: With this code doesn't force you to preset the value http://jsfiddle.net/mvy3sjro/

Comment: This directive does not accept exponents to be typed in. For example, "-2.1e-15" should be accepted as well.

Comment: @GordyD Thanks a lot. But I have a lot of various directives in my input tag (like ng-currency and ...) that can not be moved completely to the template of numberOnlyInput directive. Would you mind please give a solution that use the ng-model from the main input tag?

Comment: @GordyD: When I am having two two inputs like one is text and another one is number. In firefox, very first time it is allowing to type alphabets in number input if I come form text input. Can you please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: it allows negative number as welll

Answer (score 104):

I wrote a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KFsej) to demonstrate a great way of filtering numeric user input. The directive currently only allows positive integers, but the regex can easily be updated to support any desired numeric format.

My directive is easy to use:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="employee.age" valid-number />
```

The directive is very easy to understand:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('validNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if(!ngModelCtrl) {
        return; 
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
            var val = '';
        }
        var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '');
        if (val !== clean) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return clean;
      });

      element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I want to emphasize that **keeping model references out of the directive is important.**

I hope you find this helpful.

Big thanks to [Sean Christe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488003/sean-christe) and Chris Grimes for introducing me to the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: Good solution. I agree it is important to decouple and not directly reference the model in your directives. However, your example does not cover when someone wants to to type -1.

Comment: @GordyD Good point about the negative number support, however the original question didn't mention that in the requirements and it would be trivial to add support for it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: How can I make this work with `input type="number"`?

Comment: Additionally how can this be updated to allow for `-` and `.`?

Comment: Love it Adam. But to @bbodenmiller 's point, why does this only work with type="text" it breaks on `type="number"` :( Love it either way!

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, not my question, but definitely would accept your answer. It worked exactly as I expected.

Comment: Greate Adam it works fine.
But @AdamThomas the actual question is to allow numbers with 2 decimal values, now its not allowing to enter the decimal values.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering how i can pass a attribute to the directive which has a limit and beyond that limit user should not be able to enter anything.  Do let me know if you have any suggestions..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I was able to add an angular js $watch and restrict the user from entering more input. Thanks

Comment: Can't we just use element.on('keyPress', function() { //ifdigit preventDefault() }); ?

Comment: I think $ is missing in the line "element.bind('keypress', function(event)"

Comment: Thank you - work great.
I think you need to remove the "var" from this line:
if (angular.isUndefined(val)) { var val = '';   }

Comment: To make it perfect you need to add `ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();` between the $setViewValue(clean); and $render();

Comment: Is there any reason why this wouldn't work with AJS 1.5?

Answer (score 45):

First of all Big thanks to [Adam thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630092/adam-thomas)
I used the same Adam's logic for this with a small modification to accept the decimal values.

**Note: This will allow digits with only 2 decimal values**

Here is my [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamseernj/6guy3sp9/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="salary" valid-number />
```

**Javascript**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    });

    app.directive('validNumber', function() {
      return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          if(!ngModelCtrl) {
            return; 
          }

          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                var val = '';
            }
            var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
            var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');

            if(!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0,2);
                clean =decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
            }

            if (val !== clean) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
              ngModelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return clean;
          });

          element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode === 32) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: You should convert `val` to string before `val.replace` because it spits error `val.replace is not function` when input[type=number].

Comment: Thanks, this is working exactly like I want. However I wanted flexible amount of decimals, so I pass it as an attribute like so `decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0, attrs.validNumber);`  this was replacing the `...slice(0, 2)...`

Answer (score 10):

Use the step tag to set the minimum changeable value to some decimal number:

e.g.
step="0.01"

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="form-control" 
name="form_name" id="your_id" placeholder="Please Input a decimal number" required>
```

There is some documentation on it here:

http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/

Comment: Great!  I was using ng-pattern with a regex before. This one validates better. Thanks.

Comment: unable to bind it with angular is I include `step="0.01"`

Answer (score 7):

**DEMO** - -    **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/xh5kV/2/)**

**Directive**

```
   .directive('onlyNum', function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {

         var keyCode = [8,9,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,110];
          element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
            console.log($.inArray(event.which,keyCode));
            if($.inArray(event.which,keyCode) == -1) {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.onlyNum);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });
     };
  });
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="number" only-num>
```

Note : Do not forget include jQuery with angular js

Comment: @penner - do you know how to add special characters to the list? I've tried adding 33, 34, 35 and so forth, but I'm not having anyluck

Comment: @Davis Simply adding the keycode to the whitelist array works for me. Change line 6 to console.log(event.which); to get the right keycode.

Comment: @penner - thanks for the reply. Oddly enough, it's not working.

Comment: Figured it out  'element.on('keypress keydown', function (event)'

Comment: Modded: .directive('validNumber', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {

     var keyCode = [8,9,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,110, 190];
     var dots_used = 0;
      element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if(event.which == 190) ++dots_used;
        if(keyCode.indexOf(event.which) == -1 || (event.which == 190 && dots_used > 1)) {
            scope.$apply(function(){
                scope.$eval(attrs.onlyNum);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    });
 };

Answer (score 7):

You could easily use the ng-pattern.

```
ng-pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,?[0-9]{3}){0,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an input number directive which I belive can do just what you want.

```
<input type="number"
   ng-model="{string}"
   [name="{string}"]
   [min="{string}"]
   [max="{string}"]
   [required]
   [ng-required="{string}"]
   [ng-minlength="{number}"]
   [ng-maxlength="{number}"]
   [ng-pattern="{string}"]
   [ng-change="{string}"]>
```

the official doc is here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.number

Comment: Just want to add that by default, all modern browsers will render it with inc/dec buttons. but they can be safely removed with simple css.

Comment: The question asks how to prevent typing in non-numeric text. input[type="number"] does not prevent non-numeric text from being typed in, it only sets the field as invalid if non-numeric text is entered.

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
 <input type="text" name="number" only-digits>
```

// Just type 123

```
  .directive('onlyDigits', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function inputValue(val) {
          if (val) {
            var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

            if (digits !== val) {
              ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
              ctrl.$render();
            }
            return parseInt(digits,10);
          }
          return undefined;
        }            
        ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
      }
    };
```

// type: 123 or 123.45

```
 .directive('onlyDigits', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function inputValue(val) {
          if (val) {
            var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

            if (digits !== val) {
              ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
              ctrl.$render();
            }
            return parseFloat(digits);
          }
          return undefined;
        }            
        ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
      }
    };
```

Comment: I can put 123.444.555.666 :-(

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a directive that could be limited in range by `min` and `max` attributes like so:

`<input type="text" integer min="1" max="10" />`

so I wrote the following:

```
.directive('integer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel)
                return;

            function isValid(val) {
                if (val === "")
                    return true;

                var asInt = parseInt(val, 10);
                if (asInt === NaN || asInt.toString() !== val) {
                    return false;
                }

                var min = parseInt(attr.min);
                if (min !== NaN && asInt < min) {
                    return false;
                }

                var max = parseInt(attr.max);
                if (max !== NaN && max < asInt) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            var prev = scope.$eval(attr.ngModel);
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                // short-circuit infinite loop
                if (val === prev)
                    return val;

                if (!isValid(val)) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(prev);
                    ngModel.$render();
                    return prev;
                }

                prev = val;
                return val;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: To make it perfect you need to add `ngModel.$commitViewValue();` between the $setViewValue(clean); and $render();

Answer (score 1):

Here's my really quick-n-dirty one:

```
<!-- HTML file -->
<html ng-app="num">
  <head></head>
  <body ng-controller="numCtrl">
    <form class="digits" name="digits" ng-submit="getGrades()" novalidate >
      <input type="text" placeholder="digits here plz" name="nums" ng-model="nums" required ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" />
      <p class="alert" ng-show="digits.nums.$error.pattern">Numbers only, please.</p> 
      <br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="txt here plz" name="alpha" ng-model="alpha" required ng-pattern="/^(\D)+$/" />
      <p class="alert" ng-show="digits.alpha.$error.pattern">Text only, please.</p>
      <br>
      <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Do it!" ng-disabled="!digits.$valid" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

// Javascript file
var app = angular.module('num', ['ngResource']);
app.controller('numCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.digits = {};
});
```

This requires you include the angular-resource library for persistent bindings to the fields for validation purposes.

[Working example here](http://codepen.io/astockwell/pen/JyCva)

Works like a champ in 1.2.0-rc.3+. Modify the regex and you should be all set. Perhaps something like `/^(\d|\.)+$/` ? As always, validate server-side when you're done.

Comment: do you have a plurk for this? I can't seem to get it to work. is the capturing `()`s required?

Comment: I apologize, my answer was a bit hasty and incomplete. It's been updated and tested with an example to function.

Comment: still doesn't work for me.i don't think `angular-resource.js` has anything to do with `ng-pattern` -- it looks like an $http library

Answer (score 1):

This one seems the easiest to me:
http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/DwKZh/

(Code is not mine, I accidentally stumbled upon it)

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){
       return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
           modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
               // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input. 
               // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
               // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined
               if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
               var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
               if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
                  modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                  modelCtrl.$render();
               }         

               return transformedInput;         
           });
         }
       };
    });
```

Comment: To make it perfect you need to add `modelCtrl.$commitViewValue();` between the $setViewValue(clean); and $render();

Answer (score 1):

I modified Alan's answer above to restrict the number to the specified min/max.  If you enter a number outside the range, it will set the min or max value after 1500ms.  If you clear the field completely, it will not set anything.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="employee.age" min="18" max="99" valid-number />
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {});

app.directive('validNumber', function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            var min = +attrs.min;
            var max = +attrs.max;
            var lastValue = null;
            var lastTimeout = null;
            var delay = 1500;

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                    val = '';
                }            

                if (lastTimeout) {
                    $timeout.cancel(lastTimeout);
                }

                if (!lastValue) {
                    lastValue = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
                }

                if (val.length) {
                    var value = +val;
                    var cleaned = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, ''); 

                    // This has no non-numeric characters
                    if (val.length === cleaned.length) {
                        var clean = +cleaned;

                        if (clean < min) {
                            clean = min;
                        } else if (clean > max) {
                            clean = max;
                        }

                        if (value !== clean || value !== lastValue) {
                            lastTimeout = $timeout(function () {
                                lastValue = clean;
                                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                                ngModelCtrl.$render();
                            }, delay);
                        }
                    // This has non-numeric characters, filter them out
                    } else {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(lastValue);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                }

                return lastValue;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            element.on('$destroy', function () {
                element.unbind('keypress');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and update the `input[type="number"]` example on angular docs for works with decimals precision and I'm using this approach to solve it.

*PS: A quick reminder is that the browsers supports the characters 'e' and 'E' in the input[type="number"], because that the `keypress` event is required.*

```
angular.module('numfmt-error-module', [])
.directive('numbersOnly', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      precision: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      var currencyDigitPrecision = scope.precision;

      var currencyDigitLengthIsInvalid = function(inputValue) {
        return countDecimalLength(inputValue) > currencyDigitPrecision;
      };

      var parseNumber = function(inputValue) {
        if (!inputValue) return null;
        inputValue.toString().match(/-?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?/g).join('');
        var precisionNumber = Math.round(inputValue.toString() * 100) % 100;

        if (!!currencyDigitPrecision && currencyDigitLengthIsInvalid(inputValue)) {
          inputValue = inputValue.toFixed(currencyDigitPrecision);
          modelCtrl.$viewValue = inputValue;
        }
        return inputValue;
      };

      var countDecimalLength = function (number) { 
         var str = '' + number;
         var index = str.indexOf('.');
         if (index >= 0) {
           return str.length - index - 1;
         } else {
           return 0;
         }
      };

      element.on('keypress', function(evt) {
        var charCode, isACommaEventKeycode, isADotEventKeycode, isANumberEventKeycode;
        charCode = String.fromCharCode(evt.which || event.keyCode);
        isANumberEventKeycode = '0123456789'.indexOf(charCode) !== -1;
        isACommaEventKeycode = charCode === ',';
        isADotEventKeycode = charCode === '.';

        var forceRenderComponent = false;

        if (modelCtrl.$viewValue != null && !!currencyDigitPrecision) {
          forceRenderComponent = currencyDigitLengthIsInvalid(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
        }

        var isAnAcceptedCase = isANumberEventKeycode || isACommaEventKeycode || isADotEventKeycode;

        if (!isAnAcceptedCase) {
          evt.preventDefault();
        }

        if (forceRenderComponent) {
          modelCtrl.$render(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
        }

        return isAnAcceptedCase;
      });

      modelCtrl.$render = function(inputValue) {
        return element.val(parseNumber(inputValue));
      };

      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {

        if (!inputValue) {
          return inputValue;
        }

        var transformedInput;
        modelCtrl.$setValidity('number', true);
        transformedInput = parseNumber(inputValue);

        if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {

          modelCtrl.$viewValue = transformedInput;
          modelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
          modelCtrl.$render(transformedInput);
        }
        return transformedInput;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And in your html you can use this approach

```
<input 
  type="number" 
  numbers-only 
  precision="2" 
  ng-model="model.value" 
  step="0.10" />
```

[Here is the plunker with this snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/3tL84jOYgDLRn04aSodp?p=preview)

Comment: Did you test this? It does not working correctly. When i add decimals it adds them incorrectly.

Comment: Not working very well...when I try to delete numbers it doesn't allow it

Comment: @azuax I updated the snippet. Please check it again and if you guys need something, please ping me

Comment: @CodeArtist I updated the snippet. Please check it again and if you guys need something, please ping me

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from gordy's answer:

Good job btw. But it also allowed + in the front. This will remove it.

```
    scope.$watch('inputValue', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        var arr = String(newValue).split("");
        if (arr.length === 0) return;
        if (arr.length === 1 && (arr[0] == '-' || arr[0] === '.')) return;
        if (arr.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;
        if (isNaN(newValue)) {
            scope.inputValue = oldValue;
        }
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            if (arr[0] === "+") {
                scope.inputValue = oldValue;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a derivative that will also block the decimal point to be entered twice

HTML

```
    <input tabindex="1" type="text" placeholder="" name="salary" id="salary" data-ng-model="salary" numbers-only="numbers-only" required="required">
```

Angular

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.directive('numbersOnly', function() {
    return {
            require : 'ngModel', link : function(scope, element, attrs,  modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {

            if (inputValue == undefined) {
                return ''; //If value is required
            }

            // Regular expression for everything but [.] and [1 - 10] (Replace all)
            var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[a-z!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,<>\/?]/g, '');

            // Now to prevent duplicates of decimal point
            var arr = transformedInput.split('');

            count = 0; //decimal counter
            for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == '.') {
                    count++; //  how many do we have? increment
                }
            }

            // if we have more than 1 decimal point, delete and leave only one at the end
            while (count > 1) {
                for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    if (arr[i] == '.') {
                        arr[i] = '';
                        count = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // convert the array back to string by relacing the commas
            transformedInput = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '');

            if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }

            return transformedInput;
        });
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Adam Thomas answer you can easily make this directive more generic by adding input argument with custom regexp:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('validInput', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      "inputPattern": '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      var regexp = null;

      if (scope.inputPattern !== undefined) {
        regexp = new RegExp(scope.inputPattern, "g");
      }

      if(!ngModelCtrl) {
        return;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        if (regexp) {
          var clean = val.replace(regexp, '');
          if (val !== clean) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return clean;
        }
        else {
          return val;
        }

      });

      element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
}});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="employee.age" valid-input  
       input-pattern="[^0-9]+" placeholder="Enter an age" />
</label>
```

Live on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEagVK)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my component that will help you to allow only a particular data type. Currently supporting integer, decimal, string and time(HH:MM).

- `string` - String is allowed with optional max length
- `integer` - Integer only allowed with optional max value
- `decimal` - Decimal only allowed with optional decimal points and max value (by default 2 decimal points)
- `time` - 24 hr Time format(HH:MM) only allowed

https://github.com/ksnimmy/txDataType

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please let me know what difficulty you are facing for this?

Answer (score 0):

DECIMAL

```
directive('decimal', function() {
                return {
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                        function inputValue(val) {
                            if (val) {
                                var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

                                if (digits.split('.').length > 2) {
                                    digits = digits.substring(0, digits.length - 1);
                                }

                                if (digits !== val) {
                                    ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
                                    ctrl.$render();
                                }
                                return parseFloat(digits);
                            }
                            return "";
                        }
                        ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
                    }
                };
            });
```

DIGITS

```
directive('entero', function() {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                    function inputValue(val) {
                        if (val) {
                            var value = val + ''; //convert to string
                            var digits = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                            if (digits !== value) {
                                ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
                                ctrl.$render();
                            }
                            return parseInt(digits);
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                    ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
                }
            };
        });
```

[angular directives for validate numbers](http://aandresdev.blogspot.pe/2017/01/angular-directivas-para-validar-input.html)