# JavaScript for valid positive and negative numbers with one or no dots

Tags: javascript, regex, html, angularjs

I am using a [AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19063323/1233435) to only allow a user to enter numbers, decimals, and minus signs however I'd like to update it to allow only one dot and one negative sign at the beginning. The following is what I have now but it allows invalid inputs like `--1`:

```
val.replace( /[^0-9.-]+/g, '');
```

I need help fixing the RegEx to allow inputs like `-1`, `.1`, `-.1`, `0.1`, and `-0.1` but not like `--1`, `1.1.1`, `1-1`, `-.`, `1.`, `1.k`, and `k`.

I managed to only allow one decimal with the following but have struggled with then allowing the negative sign only at the beginning:

```
val.replace(/[^\d*[0-9]\.\d*[0-9]]/g, '');
```

Comment: I don't think `1.` should be allowed.

Comment: cool, my pattern doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think `^-?\d*\.?\d+$` is the simplest solution that works with all test cases.

Comment: tenub got it first, this looks best

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

Comment: @Matt you are right. So it should be `/^-?[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/`

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar directive, and I use this regex:

```
/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/

/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/.test("1.2.2") // false
/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/.test("1.22")  // true
/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/.test("-1")    // true
/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/.test("--1")   // false
```

Change to

```
/^\-?\d+((\.)\d+)?$/
```

to fail when the input has a comma instead of a dot.

Comment: @Beterraba unrelated would you mind sharing your directive in a gist/fiddle/plunk?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
/^-?(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex lacks of the 'starts with' `^` and 'ends with' `$` operators:

Should be

```
/^[^\d*[0-9]\.\d*[0-9]]$/g
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This handles all your test cases:

```
/^-?\d*\.?\d+$/
```

Edited to *not* match `1.`

To keep only the first instances of `-` and `.`:

```
function r(m,a,b) { return a+b.replace(new RegExp('\\'+a,'g'),''); }
"--1.2.3".replace(/(-)(.*)/g,r).replace(/(\.)(.*)/,r).replace(/[^-\.\d]/g,'')
// -1.23
```

Comment: This one appears to me to be the most robust and best answer.  Works correctly for all stated cases, as well as `-.` and `-.1`

Comment: @bbodenmiller It works in that it correctly *doesn't* match `-.`

Comment: Sorry, it's me, because it exactly the same answer than tenub has posted before you.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, I appreciate your honesty, and it's fine to keep the downvote. Fyi the reason I changed my answer was in response to the OP's comment "I don't think 1. should be allowed." It wasn't because of tenub's answer. Anyways, cheers.

Comment: @Matt: I know that it isn't your previous answer, but note that I haven't changed mine. Don't forget that you can be in the situation of tenub.

Comment: `".1k".replace(/^-?\d*\.?\d+$/, '');` doesn't seem to return `.1`. Ideas?

Comment: @bbodenmiller If you want to strip away all characters other than minuses, periods and digits, then do `".1k".replace(/[^-\.\d]/g,'')`

Comment: @bbodenmiller That's a strange regex - it's keeping extra characters that you don't want. E.g. ".1$?*+" is left unchanged.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not asking correctly but I want `--1` to return `-1`, `1.1.1` to return `1.11`, etc.

Comment: @bbodenmiller I've updated the answer. Not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps it will help. For example it won't remove a minus `-` if it's in the middle of the string - you'll have to write down more examples or describe it in more detail if want that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you something more readable

```
function validateFloat(string){
    var floatString = parseFloat(value) +"";
    return (floatString !== string);
}
```

Ok for u?

Comment: This doesn't work for '.1' since parseFloat('.1') returns 0.1.