# element.val doesnt work inside $parsers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I make a directive for number input that doesn't allow non numeric chars.
following  an answer in

[How to allow only a number (digits and decimal point) to be typed in an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/angularjs-how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in)

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    });

    app.directive('validNumber', function() {
      return {
        require: '?ngModel',
   priority: 1,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          if(!ngModelCtrl) {
            return; 
          }

          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
            var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '');
            if (val !== clean) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
              ngModelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return clean;
          });   

        }
      };
    });
```

this works.
when I replace the code

```
if (val !== clean) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
```

with:

```
 element.val(clean);
```

it doesn't always work.

it seems that element.val(clean), is being called, but something is overriding it.
Could anybody explain?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it a different way? Using `$setViewValue` is what you are supposed to and how the API gives you the right hook so that this type of functionality works correctly.

Comment: I was not sure if $setViewValue was the intention of the API here. calling $setViewValue actually, makes the $parsers function to be called again, with the new value. this is the reason you need the condition:   if (val !== clean) , otherwise you enter an infinite loop.