# How to create a directive to only number only fields without ng model

Tags: angularjs

I am using this [angular directive](http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/673/) to allow only numeric input in a text box. Here is a jsfiddle to it : http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/673/

This works. However it required `ng model`, my issue is that I have a table which I generate on-fly and each row has a numeric field for which I need to use this directive.

Now since each of the field in this row does not have a ng model this does not work.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think your directive is too tied to your model, it's never a good idea for a directive to know about the model, I took the main idea from [How to allow only a number (digits and decimal point) to be typed in an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/angularjs-how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('validNumber', function() {
   return {
       require: '?ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
           if(ngModelCtrl) {
              ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                //this will stop your from adding inputs that aren't numbers, you can change it to just affect validity
                var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '');
                if (val !== clean) {                     
                  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                  ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return clean;                  
             });
           }
           else {
               element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                   //your logic here, not sure if you want to ignore or add or whatever you want to                       do without a model, this is the place
                   var newVal = element.val() + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                   //check if newVal is ok for your and then set validity
               });
           }
    };
});
```

Another approach would be to push into the $parsers a validity check only instead of replacing the value:

```
ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
         var valid = angular.isNumber(value);
         ngModel.$setValidity('isNumber', valid);
         return valid ? value : undefined;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If restricting the typing is not an issue and you support IE10+, you may consider HTML5 number input field (e.g. `<input type="number"/>`)