# not allowing unwanted characters to input in a field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a text field and i only want to input numbers in it. I used type ="number" but i have a problem because i cannot get the decimal point. SO i've used a directive found online to restrict letters from input.

```
app.directive('onlyNum', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var keyCode = [8,9,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,110];
            element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
                console.log($.inArray(event.which,keyCode));
                if($.inArray(event.which,keyCode) == -1) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.$eval(attrs.onlyNum);
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

            });
        };
    })
```

It works fine but i can enter characters such as @,$,!,# ,& and so on.How can i restrict these characters from input also.

Comment: Note that you can do this with element.on('keydown',... and then return true for keys that are allowed and false otherwise. No need for $apply, $eval, event, preventDefault, etc

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/angularjs-how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the `input` event on your element and look if the last entered char is allowed by defining an `array` of allowed characters and check the index. If the character is not allowed, delete it:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("inputfield");
var inputText = "";
var allowedInputs = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.'];
    element.oninput = function (event) {
    if(allowedInputs.indexOf(element.value.slice(event.srcElement.selectionEnd - 1, event.srcElement.selectionEnd)) == -1)
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, event.srcElement.selectionEnd - 1) + element.value.substr(event.srcElement.selectionEnd);
};
```

```html
<input id="inputfield"/>
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcr3ky1c/2/)

You can add all characters you want to allow to the array.

EDIT: I updated the code, so no unallowed characters can be entered in between the existing characters.

Comment: can i use this in angularjs? and should i use this in my controller?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD this is plain js so you can use it with any library ;)

Comment: if i try enter smily faces given in some keyboards in some phones, the field gets stuck.is there a fix for this?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Sorry, for the late answer, I update the answer now. I tried it out with a Sony Xperia Z and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I faced another problem. The first time your solution is working.But if i goto another field and come back to my inputfield ,then i can enter characters.i tried calling your solution in a ng-click for my input field. then it's working but the problem is that field gets cleared.Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD I updated the answer again, please let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

The `keyCode` array contains the ASCII codes of all unwanted characters. You can add own numbers there, you can get them from an ascii chart. For example @ = 64, $ = 36. Be aware that most ASCII charts only give you the hexadecimal value, but the array contains decimal numbers.

EDIT: [This chart](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg) also contains decimal numbers:

Answer (score 0):

That's my custom directive that can be easily adjusted with RegEx to fit any need

http://plnkr.co/edit/dgRJkVeX6iwIbXuoMVSW?p=preview

```
.directive("numberValidation", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
        if (value) {
          var valid = value.match(/^\d+(,\d+)?$/)
          ctrl.$setValidity('invalidNumber', valid);
        }
        return valid ? value : undefined;
      });

    }
  }
});
```