# AngularJS form validation directive for number showing input errors

Tags: angularjs, jsp

Hi I am trying to validate number in text box so user can't be able to enter text(alphabets),but its not showing message.

```
 <form name="preSourceThresholdForm">
         <div class="col-md-12 h6 b" style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
            <b>Configure PreSource Threshold</b>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="preSourceThresholdGroup" ng-model="admin.preSourceThresholdGroup" value="PreSource Threshold">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 b" style="padding-top: 0px">
            PreSource Threshold
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="preSource"  ng-model="admin.preSourceThreshold" required> %
              <span ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSource.$error.number">Must Be Number!</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <input id="preSourceSave" type="button" ng-disabled="!admin.preSourceThreshold" ng-click="preSourceSave()" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" />
         </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: use this preSourceThresholdForm.preSource.$error

Comment: this link->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/angularjs-how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in can also be usefull

Comment: preSourceThresholdForm.preSource.$error showing from page loading itslef

Comment: You can use just the preSourceThresholdForm.preSource.$error.required. Since the model won't be set if what you put there isn't a number, it gives you the effect that you want.

Comment: your code is correct.  Here is yr current code working fine :   http://plnkr.co/edit/tn0mvNwxYiD77zVm4l4X?p=preview

Comment: Then why its not displaying message

Comment: show wat else is there on yr page..make a plunk with yr whole page & references

Comment: Its working fine in firebox but not in crome