# Angularjs: Allow only numbers to be typed into tel and numeric input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to prevent non-numeric characters from ever showing in tel and numeric inputs with an angularjs directive.

```
<input type="tel" ... />
<input type="number" ... />
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19063323/488168) almost perfect Stack Overflow answer, however it only works with text inputs. I need to use tel and number inputs so the correct keyboard appears on mobile devices.

How can this directive be made to work with tel AND number inputs?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('validNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if(!ngModelCtrl) {
        return; 
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
            var val = '';
        }
        var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '');
        if (val !== clean) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return clean;
      });

      element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Codepen using the almost-working directive can be found [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KFsej).

Comment: You mean that you want to support "-" ect? I believe that "tel" only works in Safari btw.

Comment: i believe you can use `pattern` for excepting numerics only.

Comment: @njfife - I am developing a cross platform ionic cordova app that runs on iOS and Android. I switch to using the tel input on iOS and number input on Android.

Comment: @maddog - pattern does not prevent the undesired characters from being typed into the input.

Answer (score 0):

> "If ever there were a most underused input type this would be it. Tel
>   offers the user a numeric keypad. If all you want from the user is a
>   number you should be using the tel input type. Forget using number,
>   because that actually includes a bunch of stuff which isn't numbers."

( from http://mobileinputtypes.com )

Did you try just changing the text type to `type="tel"`?

The directive continues to function on a computer and it displays the number keypad on mobile.