# Firefox can't clear invalid number field with Angular

Tags: angularjs, input, numbers, reset

After two hours of researches and attempts i was not able to clear a number input field when an invalid value is inserted. I've already tried setting ng-model both null, undefined and '' but none is working.

Only Firefox has this problem, i've tested the same on latest versions of Chrome and IE.

My simplified code is:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="frmToClear">
    <input type="number" name="numField" ng-model="numberModel">
  </form>
  <button ng-click="clearInput()">Clear input</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.numberModel = null;

    $scope.clearInput = function() {
        $scope.numberModel = null;
    };
}
```

Here is the fiddle where I've also added a "setZero" function to show that changing model to a valid not-null input is working well: https://jsfiddle.net/McGiogen/vhx87yq6/

### To reproduce

the error just open the link with Firefox, write any non-numeric string in the input field and press "Clear input" button. Nothing will happen.

### Browsers tested:

- Firefox 40.0.3
- Firefox dev edition 42.0a2
- Chrome 45.0.2454.93
- IE 11.0.9600.17959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use an input text and validate user input through a custom directive.

See this link for a better explanation:

[How to allow only a number (digits and decimal point) to be typed in an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in-an-input)

if you want to allow + and - modify the regex with something like that:

```
[^0-9\-\.\+]
```

Comment: I think this is a Firefox bug so, as said by @cullimorer, this can be a correct workaround to temporary solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

put '' in place of null

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.numberModel = null;

    $scope.clearInput = function() {
        $scope.numberModel = '';
    };

    $scope.setZero = function() {
       $scope.numberModel = 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I've already tried this solution and it is not working

Comment: It doesnt clear if the input has a string and not number cause it has error but if you have a correct number it set it to empty.

Comment: I checked it on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues between cross-browsers when it comes to input fields. Here's an article that can give you all the information you require.

https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/

I would solve the problem by displaying a message to the user telling them to enter a valid number and then using Angular's built in validation to prevent incorrect input.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="frmToClear">
    <input required type="number" name="numField" ng-model="numberModel">
  </form>
  <div ng-show="!frmToClear.$valid">Please enter a valid number only</div>
  <button ng-click="clearInput()" ng-disabled="!frmToClear.$valid">Clear input</button>
  <button ng-click="setZero()" ng-disabled="!frmToClear.$valid">Set zero</button>
</div>
```