# Only allow positive and negative 2 point decimal directive

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I needed a directive to allow only 2 point decimals and I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27163833/5229041

However, I can't seem to figure out how to fix the regex to also allow an optional `-` for negative numbers as well.

(I tried asking in the answer comments, but I'm not allowed to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply change this line

```
var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
```

with this

```
var clean = val.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9\.]/g, '');
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I edit my answer with a new  one. I test it and seams to work

Comment: @MarcoMorelliMoretti oh wow this works perfectly! Thanks a bunch, I've been fighting with this for the past 3 hours

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's working fine for me, i can't input the string `2.3.4`

Answer (score 1):

In regex `-?` means `-` is optional. So just add that