# Angular directive: Allow just numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is [a sample angular directive to prevent typing non-numeric keys (StackOverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in-an-input/19037037#19037037).
I want to write something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMShafiee/u1w9v2m7/) to use the is-number directive in several inputs. Please consider that since I have various different directives in my inputs, I cannot use the same template as suggested in the update of mentioned answer above.

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myNnumber1 = 1;
    $scope.myNnumber2 = 1;
});

app.directive('isNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element) {   
            scope.$watch(element.ngModel, function(newValue,oldValue) {
                newValue = String(newValue);
                newValue = newValue.replace('۰', '0').replace('۱', '1').replace('۲', '2').replace('۳', '3').replace('۴', '4').replace('۵', '5').replace('۶', '6').replace('۷', '7').replace('۸', '8').replace('۹', '9');
                var arr = String(newValue).split("");
                if (arr.length === 0) return;
                if (arr.length === 1 && (arr[0] == '-' || arr[0] === '.' )) return;
                if (arr.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;
                if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                    element.ngModel = oldValue;
                }
            });
        }
   };
```

***Update:***
Please consider that I need to do some processes to convert non English numbers and so on. I created [a new fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AMShafiee/9yakgxq6/) based on the the Angular_10's answer. Now, every thing is fine except the cursor position while typing Persian numbers. When I type A Persian Number, it is replaced with English equivalent number, but the cursor suddenly jumps to the end.

Comment: Please elaborate your question in detail what you want to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: @Angular_10 [The js and html](http://jsfiddle.net/AMShafiee/u1w9v2m7/) code that I have written using a directive to prevent entering non numeric keys does not work. Please check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMShafiee/u1w9v2m7/) and let me know how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the below directive. This directive converts persian number and do not let no numbers to be typed in the text box. Special thanks to Angular_10. I awarded 50 bounties to him for his help.

```
app.directive('fixPersianAndNoNumberInput', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
            function inputValue(val) {
                if (val) {
                    let numeric = parseInt(String(val).replace('۰', '0').replace('۱', '1').replace('۲', '2').replace('۳', '3').replace('۴', '4').replace('۵', '5').replace('۶', '6').replace('۷', '7').replace('۸', '8').replace('۹', '9').replace(' ', '000').replace(/[^- 0-9]/g, ''));
                    if (numeric !== val) {
                        controller.$setViewValue(numeric);
                        controller.$render();
                        let value;
                        let updateOn, debounce;
                        if (controller.$options) {
                            if (controller.$options.getOption) {
                                updateOn = controller.$options.getOption('updateOn');
                                debounce = controller.$options.getOption('debounce');
                            } else {
                                updateOn = controller.$options.updateOn;
                                debounce = controller.$options.debounce;
                            }
                        }
                        if (updateOn === 'blur' || debounce) {
                            value = controller.$viewValue;
                            for (let i = controller.$parsers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                value = controller.$parsers[i](value);
                            }
                        } else {
                            value = controller.$$rawModelValue;
                        }
                        for (let j = controller.$formatters.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                            value = controller.$formatters[j](value);
                        }
                        controller.$viewValue = value;
                        controller.$render();
                    }
                    return numeric;
                }
                return undefined;
            }

            controller.$parsers.push(inputValue);
            controller.$formatters.push((value) => {
                if ([undefined, null, ''].indexOf(value) === -1) {
                   return $filter('currency')(value, '', 0);
                }
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6):

OK ! Looking at your requirement I've took liberty and wrote more customised directive.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qckvhyuw/4/) for the same

**Problem**

The example from which you referred and made changes to the given directive is causing the issue.

1. Your $scope variable names are wrong in HTML/JS ($scope.myNnumber1 = 1;
   $scope.myNnumber2 = 1; in JS and in HTML it was ng-model="myNumber1")
2. You are accessing `element ng-model` and trying to modify it through directive which is bad practice and also the root cause for directive to not to work.As you are not changing the `ng-model` value but in turn modifying HTML element value which angular will not recognise.
3. More over using `$watch` in directive is not always preferable for performance sake.

**Solution**

```
app.directive('isNumber', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            function inputValue(val) {
                if (val) {
                    var numeric = val.replace(/[^- 0-9]/g, '');

                    if (numeric !== val) {
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(numeric );
                        ctrl.$render();
                    }
                    return numeric;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
        }
    };

});
```

When controller communication is required from directive we can pass Controller as 4 param in the link function.From that Ctrl param we can modify/view things from controller scope.

Using some basic regex expression to find out what is the entered input and set it in the controller scope object view value.

```
ctrl.$setViewValue(numeric); //to set the value in the respective ngModdel
ctrl.$render(); //to display the changed value
```

More about [$setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue)

Comment: Please check the update and consider that I need to do some processes to convert non English numbers. How can I replace these non English numbers to English ones? (I also have updated my original fiddle.)

Comment: What are non English numbers ? If you are referring to user entering some non English keyboard values then you must consider using some external libraries to do such kind of conversion to normal numbers

Comment: You could capture the cursor position before the $render, and then set it back afterward.

`var cursor_pos = element.prop('selectionStart') - 1;
   ctrl.$setViewValue(numeric);
   ctrl.$render();
   element[0].setSelectionRange(cursor_pos, cursor_pos);`